# wildfly 14 services missing or failed during deployment

Tags: java, servlets, undertow

I'm working on migrating my application from `jboss 4` to `wildfly 14` the former works on `jdk 6` and the latter supports `jdk 8`. While deploying I'm getting the following exception:

> {\"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\"timesheet.war\\".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService\" => \"Failed to start service
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010009: Servlet customerworkflowmappingBean of type class in.textech.workflow.customerworkflowmappingBean does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet\"}}

Comment: In your webapp classpath you may have some jar files (like servlet.jar) with classes that are already provided by WildFly packages. Try to remove them.

Comment: I couldn't find it... :(

Answer (score 0):

In your WildFly, there is undertow subsystem. It checks if every servlet is extending the HttpServlet class or not.

customerworkflowmappingBean - Is it extending HttpServlet?

Comment: Is there any way to allow classes which are not implementing HttpServlet by undertow?

Comment: It will Depend which methods are getting implemented in the class. Can you share the code of customerworkflowmappingBean

Comment: Thanks... 
Actually this how it starts...
public class customerworkflowmappingBean
{
...}